# How to rename ftp disk directory with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, ftp, directory, rename

I read Laravel's filesystem documentation and searched a bit about rename a directory in Laravel but couldn't find a proper way to rename a directory. I have directories with many files in ftp disk and I want to rename them when I want using Laravel.

Comment: directly rename manually and use that in code

Comment: I don't want do it manually!

Comment: Do you have the ftp connection set up in your `config/filesystems.php`?